# Can a <button> in HTML do something without javascript?

Tags: html, button

I have a web page that has a button. Currently I am binding this button to a javascript handler that makes the page redirect to a given URL when it is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button class="click-me">Clike me to navigate</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.click-me').on('click', function() { window.location = '/myloc'; });
```

I am now trying to build a fallback (no-javascript) version of this page. I would like this button to do the same job but without using javascript. In other words, I am trying to make this button functional even if javascript of the browser is disabled.

I know this can be achieved by form (as shown below). But I am looking for any cleaner implementation.

```
<form name="hack" action="/myloc">
  <button type="submit" class="click-me">Click me to navigate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If you get it to work without JavaScript, you won't need the JS version at all, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use an `a` element, that's what they're *for*:

```
<a class="click-me" href="/path/to/whatever/page">Click me to navigate</a>
```

And then simply *style* it as a `button`.

For example with the following CSS:

```
.clickMe {
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -ms-appearance: button;
    -o-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/znfDb/).

(Obviously this assumes the use of a browser that supports the `appearance` (or vendor-prefixed versions) CSS property.)

References:

- [`appearance` (albeit it's the `-moz-` prefixed MDN documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance).
- [`appearance` property, at the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css3-ui-20040511/#appearance).
- [Unfortunately-dropped CSS3 features (at the W3C)](http://wiki.csswg.org/spec/css4-ui#dropped-css3-features).

Comment: +1 although the button wouldn't look like a user agent / OS specific button (unless you are handling the styling separately)

Comment: It's pretty easy to make it look button like too with CSS http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/01/10/pressed-button-state-with-css3/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on firefox or google chrome in 2023, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question asked in the heading, yes, the [`button` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) can “do things” without JavaScript. With `type=submit`, it submits a form, as in the example at the end of the question. With `type=reset`, it wipes out all user input from the form. It’s just `type=button` (the default when the element is outside any form) that is JavaScript-dependent and does not do anything without scripting.

To answer the question you should have asked: Use links, Luke. You can style a link look pretty much like a button if you want (might make sense in an application-like context), even using just CSS 2.1 plus optional CSS3 enhancements like rounded corners.

Comment: Fortunately, modern Web usage doesn't require buttons to look like they are depressing in 3d anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add implementation of button click (if that references any webpage) by adding an `<a>` tag before it. For example:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
    <button>Youtube</button>
</a>
```

This doesn't need any JavaScript as far as I know.