# HTML Button : Navigate to Other Page - Different Approaches

Tags: html, button

There are multiple ways to create a HTML button to navigate to other page.

**Method 1**

```
<button id="btn_click">Click Me</button>
<script>
$('#btn_click').on('click', function() { window.location = 'http://www.google.com'; });
</script>
```

- Advantage: Separate JS from HTML (MVC)
- Disadvantage: Long codes, rely on JS
- Note: jQuery selector is optional, can use traditional JavaScript

**Method 2**

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'">Click Me</button>
```

- Advantage: 1-liner, no need assign ID to button
- Disadvantage: Mix JS with HTML, rely on JS

**Method 3**

```
<a class="click-me" href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>
<style>
.clickMe {
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -ms-appearance: button;
    -o-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}​
</style>
```

- Advantage: no need to rely on JS
- Disadvantage: Looks like a fake button, IE9+ required ( `appearance` is a CSS3 property )
- Note: this is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13348602/188331)

**Method 4**

```
<form action="http://www.google.com">
<button>Click Me</button>
</form>
```

- Advantage: Shortest code, no need to rely on JS
- Disadvantage: Misuse of `<form>` tag. Does not work if there is another submit button

Programmers, which approaches is the most efficient (and hence used widely), and why?

*Note:* can we make this as community wiki ?

Comment: Question reworded. Please re-consider. I think I might have an answer `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make a link. A link is a link. A link navigates to another page. That is what links are for and everybody understands that. So Method 3 is the only correct method in my book.

I wouldn't want my link to look like a button at all, and when I do, I still think functionality is more important than looks.

Buttons are less accessible, not only due to the need of Javascript, but also because tools for the visually impaired may not understand this Javascript enhanced button well.

Method 4 would work as well, but it is more a trick than a real functionality. You abuse a form to post 'nothing' to this other page. It's not clean.

Comment: However, it's a common practice to make navigation looks like button in web-based systems, such as Content Management System (CMS)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Maybe, but when you talk about pages, it sounds to me like a site, not like a web application. In (specialized) applications, different rules apply, because you write them for a specific user base. A website should be for everybody. Still, also in a CMS, I would prefer links, and maybe add some CSS. It seems like a lot of code, but you only need the CSS once and simply add a class to the links that need to look like buttons.

Comment: Agree with you. a CSS-decorated `<a>` tag is efficient & adequate in most cases.

Comment: Also in mobile apps, people are used to buttons.

Answer (score 2):

I use method 3 because it's the most understandable for others (whenever you see an `<a>` tag, you know it's a link) and when you are part of a team, you have to make simple things ;).

And finally I don't think it's useful and efficient to use JS simply to navigate to an other page.